# Seleccionar un id especifico Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

tengo un pequeño problema.
Tengo una especie de carrusel de historias de facebook, y quiero que al hacer clic en cada historia, se reproduzca una animación. Lo hago por id pero solo funciona la animación con el primer id que se encuentra en el HTML, y quiero que al hacer click en cualquier historia se reproduzca la animación correctamente.

```js
$(document).each(function(){
    $("#history").mouseover(function(){
        $("#text-perfil").css("display", "block");
        $("#history-img").css("height", "70%");
    });

    $("#history").mouseout(function(){
        $("#text-perfil").css("display", "none");
        $("#history-img").css("height", "80%");
    });
});
```

```css
.histoy-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    margin-top: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* outline: 1px solid green; */
}

.history {
    position: relative;
    width: 29%;
    height: 175px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.3) 1px 1.95px 10px;

    border-bottom-left-radius: 24px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 24px;
    margin: 1%;

    /* outline: 1px solid red; */
}

.history-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;

    object-fit: cover;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.history-img > img, .history {
    border-top-left-radius: 24px;
    border-top-right-radius: 24px;
}

.history-interaction {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

.history-interaction > p {
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
    
}

.text-perfil {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    color: var(--secondaryColor);
    top: 15px;
    animation: reveal .2s linear;
}

/* ------ [ANIMACION Y HOVER] ------ */
@keyframes reveal {
    from {
        top: 30px;
    } to {
        top: 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- History Container -->
            <div class="histoy-container">
                <div class="history" id="history">
                    <div class="history-img" id="history-img">
                        <img src="./Public/Img/IMAGEN.jfif" alt="" srcset="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="history-interaction" id="history-interaction">
                        <p> @lana_latam </p>
                        <div class="content-text-perfil" >
                            <p class="text-perfil" id="text-perfil"> See Perfil </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="history" id="history">
                    <div class="history-img" id="history-img">
                        <img src="./Public/Img/IMAGEN.jfif" alt="" srcset="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="history-interaction" id="history-interaction">
                        <p> @lana_latam </p>
                        <div class="content-text-perfil" >
                            <p class="text-perfil" id="text-perfil"> See Perfil </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="history" id="history">
                    <div class="history-img" id="history-img">
                        <img src="./Public/Img/IMAGEN.jfif" alt="" srcset="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="history-interaction" id="history-interaction">
                        <p> @lana_latam </p>
                        <div class="content-text-perfil" >
                            <p class="text-perfil" id="text-perfil"> See Perfil </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Como dije anteriormente, solo funciona la primera, pero la idea es que funcione con todas, no se si me explico. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacerlo?

Estoy atento a sus respuestas :D

Comment: En HTML los id deben ser únicos, y tu los has repetido todos en casi todos los elementos de tu código. Si necesitas referenciar elementos parecidos puedes repetir clases, pero no id.  Cualquier respuesta que te den sin solucionar eso será una chapuza, así que yo de ti empezaria corrigiéndolo y acostúmbrate a no repetirlos más (y no es la primera vez que se te advierte del uso de ids repetidos en este sitio).

Comment: Entonces ¿cómo haría para seleccionarlos, si la idea es que los elementos se creen al momento de un usuario haga una publicación? Quiero decir, voy a tener varios elementos que se crean, y tengo que saber cuál se está clickeando para hacer la animación justo en ese. Con clases ya lo probe y tengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: Mira de entender mi respuesta. Cualquier duda pregunta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, perdona un poco mi ignorancia soy nuevo usando Jquery

Comment: No te preocupes, no tengo nada que perdonar, solo faltaría, jeej.  Pero recuerda, **repetir id nunca es la solución de nada y en HTML no deben repetirse jamás**. :-)  Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta respuesta he borrado todos los id, pues no los vamos a usar.

Tampoco vamos a usar un `each` de todos los elementos del DOM como tenias, pues no hace falta con los selectores de jquery.

En su lugar he usado las clases, que tenian los mismo nombres, y una vez se detecta la acción, mouseover o mouseout, he buscado en el interior del elemento que la recibe (representado por `$(this)`) sus otros elementos mediante el uso de **find()** de jquery.

Ejemplo completo:

```js
$(".history").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).find(".text-perfil").css("display", "block");
  $(this).find(".history-img").css("height", "70%");
});

$(".history").mouseout(function() {
  $(this).find(".text-perfil").css("display", "none");
  $(this).find(".history-img").css("height", "80%");
});
```

```css
.histoy-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  /* outline: 1px solid green; */
}

.history {
  position: relative;
  width: 29%;
  height: 175px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.3) 1px 1.95px 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 24px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 24px;
  margin: 1%;
  /* outline: 1px solid red; */
}

.history-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.history-img>img,
.history {
  border-top-left-radius: 24px;
  border-top-right-radius: 24px;
}

.history-interaction {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.history-interaction>p {
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
}

.text-perfil {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  color: var(--secondaryColor);
  top: 15px;
  animation: reveal .2s linear;
}


/* ------ [ANIMACION Y HOVER] ------ */

@keyframes reveal {
  from {
    top: 30px;
  }
  to {
    top: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- History Container -->
<div class="histoy-container">
  <div class="history">
    <div class="history-img">
      <img src="./Public/Img/IMAGEN.jfif" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
    <div class="history-interaction">
      <p> @lana_latam </p>
      <div class="content-text-perfil">
        <p class="text-perfil"> See Perfil </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="history">
    <div class="history-img">
      <img src="./Public/Img/IMAGEN.jfif" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
    <div class="history-interaction">
      <p> @lana_latam </p>
      <div class="content-text-perfil">
        <p class="text-perfil"> See Perfil </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="history">
    <div class="history-img">
      <img src="./Public/Img/IMAGEN.jfif" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
    <div class="history-interaction">
      <p> @lana_latam </p>
      <div class="content-text-perfil">
        <p class="text-perfil"> See Perfil </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Llego un poco tarde, pero al ver que ya resolvieron la duda dejo una solución en la que no usa Js. La PseudoClase :Hover en css es como el  evento mouseover en jquery o Over en JavaScript.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.histoy-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.history:hover .content-text-perfil{
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
}

.history {
  width: 29%;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 175px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.3) 1px 1.95px 10px;
}

.history-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
}

.history-img img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.history-interaction{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 30%;   
}

.content-text-perfil{
  transition: 0.3s;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="histoy-container">
<div class="history" id="history">
  <div class="history-img" id="history-img">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SOqaKDq.gif" alt="" srcset="">
  </div>
  <div class="history-interaction" id="history-interaction">
    <p> @lana_latam </p>
    <div class="content-text-perfil">
      <p class="text-perfil" id="text-perfil"> See Perfil </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="history" id="history">
  <div class="history-img" id="history-img">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SOqaKDq.gif" alt="" srcset="">
  </div>
  <div class="history-interaction" id="history-interaction">
    <p> @lana_latam </p>
    <div class="content-text-perfil">
      <p class="text-perfil" id="text-perfil"> See Perfil </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="history" id="history">
  <div class="history-img" id="history-img">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SOqaKDq.gif" alt="" srcset="">
  </div>
  <div class="history-interaction" id="history-interaction">
    <p> @lana_latam </p>
    <div class="content-text-perfil">
      <p class="text-perfil" id="text-perfil"> See Perfil </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Un consejo amigo, los ID solo se usan para elementos unicos, es decir no vamos a agregarle el mismo ID a dos elementos diferentes porque no es su funcion, para eso usamos las clases, saludos y que tengas buen dia.